# Modify .NET ApiController "BadResult()" to print custom JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, json-api

I am using the .NET pattern where my controller action has a signature as such

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTimeSeries(string deviceId, string tag) { ... }
```

and inside the controller I want to send a custom error message adhering to the [JSON API Spec](http://jsonapi.org/examples/#error-objects)

My goal is when encountering an error to use

```
return BadRequest(someJSONErrorObject);
```

or

```
return NotFound(someJSONErrorObject);
```

rather than throw an exception.

Currently if I do

```
return BadRequest(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someJSONErrorObject));
```

the JSON I get back looks like

```
{
"Message": "{\"data\":null,\"errors\":[{\"detail\":\"The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.\"}],\"meta\":null}"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom `IHttpActionResult`

```
public class CustomResponseResult<T> : IHttpActionResult {

    public CustomResponseResult(HttpStatusCode statusCode, T content, HttpRequestMessage request) {
        Content = content;
        Request = request;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public T Content { get; private set; }
    public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; private set; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; private set; }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute());
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage Execute() {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(StatusCode, Content);
        response.RequestMessage = Request;
        response.ReasonPhrase = StatusCode.ToString();
        return response;
    }
}
```

and then in order to maintain usability create extension methods

```
public static class ApiControllerExtensions {
    public static IHttpActionResult BadRequest<T>(this ApiController controller, T content) {
        return controller.CustomResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, content);
    }

    public static IHttpActionResult NotFound<T>(this ApiController controller, T content) {
        return controller.CustomResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, content);
    }

    public static IHttpActionResult CustomResponse<T>(this ApiController controller, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T content) {
        var request = controller.Request;
        var result = new CustomResponseResult<T>(statusCode, content, request);
        return result;
    }
}
```

that allowed the calls wanted

```
return this.BadRequest(someJSONErrorObject);
```

or

```
return this.NotFound(someJSONErrorObject);
```

Comment: This works for the `Ok(someJSONDataObject)`, but `BadRequest()` constructor only takes a string or a state.  Whatever is in the string gets assigned to the `Message` property.

Comment: Ok i got around this in my code. Let do a quick check

Comment: Yeah I was struggling with that `this.BadRequest()` part...any way around that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are struggling with. the extension method would be `this.BadRequest<T>(...)`. `this.BadRequest()` would be the original method on `ApiController`.

Comment: What is your expected result for `this.BadResult()`. If I know that then I could probably suggest an update to the extensions

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  To clarify, why is it necessary to use `this.BadRequest()` instead of just `BadRequest()` in the controller?

Comment: Right. the use of `this` is because of the extension methods. Without `this` you would be referring to the instance methods and not the extension methods

Comment: Just had an idea. If you create a class that inherits from `ApiController` and then create a `BadRequest<T>` method to wrap the extension method then you should be able to use it without the `this`

Answer (score 0):

Create custom error class where you can set the http status and error message. Create a custom exception class to throw your custome error messag. Create a Global Exception filter which will send you custom exception in json format.

Comment: My goal was not to throw an exception in the controller but to explicitly `return BadRequest()`.  When you `return BadRequest()` it doesn't run through the exception filter